# Sorting Linked List Alphabetically

Tags: java, sorting

I am working on a data structures assignment so I am not using the built-in Linkedlist in java. I need to sort the nodes alphabetically. Can I use this type of sorting that's built in? The assignment isn't stressing our sorting method so I'm looking for the easiest thing. The IDE complains about my list parameter which makes me think maybe this isn't a possibility?:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>()
{
@Override
public int compare(String text1, String text2)
{
    return text1.compareToIgnoreCase(text2);
}
});
```

Comment: What does the IDE complain about, precisely?

Comment: From the problems listed below, I would suggest just writing your own sorting. The simplest is bubble sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can only sort lists which implement java.util.List using the built in methods.

Comment: But you can make the list implement the List interface and then you could do the built-in sorting.

Comment: Agreed, but given the OP was talking about a data structures assignment and not wanting to use the built in classes it seemed fair to outline the only way to make that work is to implement that interface.

Answer (score 4):

To be able to use the built-in sorting function your list structure must implement the `List<T>` interface.

This is according to the signature:

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

This means that your custom list should provide the implementation of ALL the methods described in `List` interface, you can find them [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

You should have something like

```
class MyCustomList<T> implements List<T> {
 ...
}
```

Comment: If I implement the List interface though, I guess I'm not really building my own list from scratch, so I'll have to get dirty with the sorting..

Comment: That's not exactly true, if you implement the interface you just define how the list is accesses by external objects but providing your own implementation. This is required just because the `Collection.sort(...)` method must know how to access the list. In any case, being a data structure assignment, I guess you should provide your own sorting algorithm function too.